# Iphone Developer Program

Tags: iphone, sdk

Well im on the edge about paying $99 dollars to join the Iphone Developer Program, I have the sdk, but im wondering if the program comes with programming lessons or tutorials,

If it doesnt do any of you know where i can learn to make game with opengl es for the iphone/ipod touch??

So my main question is where can i get some good tutorials on programming games/apps for the iphone and ipod touch, and does the Iphone Developer Program come with good lessons on how to program?

Thank You
-techy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Paying the $99 does not give you any additional content or lessons. You already have access to the Apple-supplied sample code. The SDK only provides the ability to test your application on actual hardware, and it allows you to submit applications to the App Store.

The best place to go for beginning tutorials is the [Stanford CS193P](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/index.php) course which is available online through iTunesU. I would download all this content soon, as it is not guaranteed to be available when the next term starts.

Other than that, I would Google the exact terms that you had in your question: "Open GL ES" "iPhone" "cocoa touch tutorial" There's a ton of content available.

Comment: Just to second mmc, I also recommend the CS193P course. There are other places to get all of the information but the course is a great resource for learning iPhone development and the lectures help make the material easy to digest.

Answer (score 1):

To the resources available with iPhone Dev Package: Yes, there are many resources availible to you as a developer.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/

Comment: so do these come with the iphone dev program or are they ones u get when u sign up for free

Comment: No, I believe it is the same content availible with the free account.

Comment: You don't get more docs/resources/sample code by paying the $99, you just get the ability to put apps on devices for debugging and submit them to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many developer tutorials on the net, I think that stanford even released the lessons as videos for free in itunes.

Of course, it depends why you are getting into it. Apple just released facts that there are 100,000 developers, with >60,000 apps in the store. If you are doing it for fun, or to learn something new, then great. If you want to get rich creating fart apps, your time has passed.

Answer (score -1):

There is lots of book available for [iPhone development program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/).

Comment: -1 That's neither an answer, nor very helpful to any future visitors to this question.